# Convert string to day number IN SQL

Tags: mysql

There is a SQL table like below and I want to convert the UnixDates in string into day numbers as in output. Can you please assist me with this matter?

[image: Table1 ID UnixTimes 1 1632862800,1632949200]

```
OUTPUT:

    1- 21,22
    2- 22
    3- 22,23
    4- 21,22,23
    5- 24,25
```

Comment: Fix your data model!  Don't store numbers as strings!  Don't store multiple values in a column!

Comment: [FROM_UNIXTIME()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

Comment: What kind of date is "21"? Are those even unix timestamps?

Comment: Thanks, @GordonLinoff but I continue a project. Unfortunately, they created the DB structure like this. So, I'm changing the structure from time to time but I need to convert them temporarily. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @SalmanA, if we convert the '1632171600' to human date we obtain September 21. 21 is the day of the month. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Akina, Yes I'm  using that function (from_unixtime) but the function is converting just only the first column, not after commas. Thanks

Comment: Divide it to separate values then apply the function. What is **precise** MySQL version?

Comment: @SalmanA I'm using this web site -> https://www.unixtimestamp.com/ and checked it out I got "Tue Sep 21 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)" thanks

Comment: @bos never mind that. If there is maximum 3 items in a row then there is a simple solution. Then there are tricks for _n_ items in CSV.

Comment: @Akina, MariaDB 10.4.10

Comment: Use recursive CTE and parse your CSV value to separate values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS ( SELECT id, 
                DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(unixdates), '%d') one_day, 
                SUBSTRING(TRIM(LEADING SUBSTRING_INDEX(unixdates, ',', 1) FROM unixdates) FROM 2) unixdates
         FROM test 
         UNION ALL
         SELECT id, 
                DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(unixdates), '%d'), 
                SUBSTRING(TRIM(LEADING SUBSTRING_INDEX(unixdates, ',', 1) FROM unixdates) FROM 2)
         FROM cte
         WHERE unixdates <> ''
         )
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(one_day) days 
FROM cte
GROUP BY id;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=31cf8c95107efca00a9df7d5eae2d13d

Comment: Hi @Akina, Actually, I'm using Mysql (5.7.34) and the above code didn't work. The message of the error is "Unrecognized statement type (near WITH)". Thank you.

Comment: @Bos ??? You have told in the comment that "@Akina, MariaDB 10.4.10 – Bos 21 hours ago"

Comment: Yes @Akina, MariaDB, but ı convert the above code into the Mysql. It worked :) Thank you so much! How can I mark your answer as solved? Thanks